# php extracting first image from html string, remove all images tag, and truncate html string

Tags: php, html, parsing, truncate

I save in database an html content from tinymce editor, so I would want display this html content on php page, but in beautiful way. 
I would want first check if in html string is present an image, if it is present then display it first in php page. Then I would want display some text on right of image, truncating it first 200 words, but it must maintain html because it is possible that are present also links not only simple text.

Is there a php library or php class for manipulating html and for truncating html string for "read more" functionality?

Comment: Is there a question in there somewhere?

Comment: I save in database html content from tinymce editor, so now I want display this html content on page, but in beautiful way. I would want first check if in html string is present an image, if it is present then display it first in page. Then I would want display some text on right of image, truncating it first 200 words, but it must maintain html because it is possible that are present also links not only text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a nice tool:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Funnily enough it even has the example your looking for on the front page.

EDIT:

PHP actually comes with its own library for handling HTML documented at: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php
Also take a look at http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/

Comment: good thank a lot. Is there something also for truncate html string?

Comment: I've modified by answer.  The PHP DOM classes will give you full control over valid HTML, this will give the advantage of not relying on an additional library, however looking at it, it can get pretty fiddly.  The phpquery looks very useful and something akin to jquery, if you're familiar with that.  The documentation describes a set of 'replace' functions which i believe is what you're looking for.