# Remove images which are small in a string

Tags: php, image, detect

I write this post because I have this problem:

I have a string with html characters.

What I want is to remove from this string, all images which are smaller than 10px width. How could I do this in PHP?

I've been thinking in the use of some loop but I don't know how to implement that. Can somebody help me?

Comment: you should provide what the content of your string would look like and ask for a regex to do what you want.

Comment: How would PHP have any understanding of the display size of an `img` element? [tag:php] is *server-side*, you may want to use JavaScript, but without context I don't know what to suggest.

Comment: This question is very similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12609063/php-extracting-first-image-from-html-string-remove-all-images-tag-and-truncate/12609214#12609214
My answer listed several libraries to search for html elements.  You could expand on that and get the dimension attributes to determine the.. dimensions

Comment: are you talking about <img tags, or characters that are less than 10px in width?

Comment: This is a bit difficult to answer. Many times the dimensions of an image are not embedded within the img element. 

In this case, you'd have to open each image to determine its dimensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
$final = array();
$images = array();
$template = "<img src='%d.jpg' height='%d' width='%d' />";


for($i = 0; $i < 10;  $i++)
{
    $height = mt_rand(9, 12);
    $weight = mt_rand(9, 12);
    $images[] = sprintf($template , $i,$height,$weight);

}


var_dump($images);


foreach($images as $image)
{
    $attribute = simplexml_load_string($image);
    $attribute = $attribute->attributes();

    if((int) $attribute['height'] <  10 or (int) $attribute['width'] < 10)
        continue ;
    $final[] = $image;
}

var_dump($final);
```

Output

```
array
  0 => string '<img src='0.jpg' height='11' width='9' />' (length=41)
  1 => string '<img src='1.jpg' height='12' width='9' />' (length=41)
  2 => string '<img src='2.jpg' height='10' width='11' />' (length=42)
  3 => string '<img src='3.jpg' height='12' width='11' />' (length=42)
  4 => string '<img src='4.jpg' height='11' width='9' />' (length=41)
  5 => string '<img src='5.jpg' height='9' width='11' />' (length=41)
  6 => string '<img src='6.jpg' height='9' width='9' />' (length=40)
  7 => string '<img src='7.jpg' height='10' width='9' />' (length=41)
  8 => string '<img src='8.jpg' height='12' width='9' />' (length=41)
  9 => string '<img src='9.jpg' height='10' width='10' />' (length=42)
array
  0 => string '<img src='2.jpg' height='10' width='11' />' (length=42)
  1 => string '<img src='3.jpg' height='12' width='11' />' (length=42)
  2 => string '<img src='9.jpg' height='10' width='10' />' (length=42)
```

Comment: this is not exactly what I want but it really helped me. In order to remove the images I don't want, I could use a preg_replace. Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I would try http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php